# Set $_GET Using Yii HiddenField Method

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to set my `$_GET` if a button is selected. Currently, I am trying to set this by using the following command: `CHTML::hiddenField('hidden', $displayData = "option1");` but this only reloads the page. Any suggestions?

Controller:

```
<?php
    $data1 = new CArrayDataProvider(.......){
        .......
    }

    $data2 = new CArrayDataProvider(.......){
        .......
    }

    if(isset($_GET['export'])){
        $displayData = $_GET['export'] == 'option1' ? $data1 -> getData() : $data2 ->getData();

        // Export CSV FILE Content here

    }
?>
```

View:

```
<?php
    // BUTTON 1
    CHTML::hiddenField('hidden', $displayData = "option1");
    // The button and other data
?>

 <?php
    // BUTTON 2
    CHTML::hiddenField('hidden', $displayData = "option2");
    // The button and other data
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read Yii docs about hidden field: [**link**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#hiddenField-detail)

```
public static string hiddenField(string $name, string $value='', array $htmlOptions=array ( ))
```

So your code in views should be something like this:

```
CHTML::hiddenField('export', option1);
or
CHTML::hiddenField('export', option2);
```

Also, you must understand that hiddenField is not a button or form, it won't send data to anywhere.
To send some data from user to the server you should use CActiveForm with your hidden field.
You can find example [**here**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.view)

Comment: Thanks @AxeIPAL, I had read through the Yii docs, but wasn't able to figure this out. Appreciate your help!